# Table sorter not working from Ajax, PHP

Tags: php, ajax, html-table, tablesorter

I'm using AJAX to return database entries from SQL to HTML.

I'd like to use tablesorter JS to then arrange the database entries.

The initial issue I'm having is the Table rows in my table are all individually wrapped in TBODY's, which I assume is causing tablesorter JS not to work.

Here is the HTML

```
<table id="results" class="tablesorter">    

      <thead>
             <tr>  
                 <th>Event</th>  
                 <th>Venue</th>  
                 <th>Genre</th>  
                 <th>Date</th> 
                 <th>Price</th>  
            </tr>  
             </thead>

              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td>egg presents</td>  
                      <td>egg</td>  
                      <td>techno</td>  
                      <td>2018-01-08</td> 
                      <td>0.00</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>


              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td>fabric presents</td>  
                      <td>fabric</td>  
                      <td>techno</td>  
                      <td>2018-01-08</td> 
                      <td>0.00</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>


              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td>fabric presents</td>  
                      <td>fabric</td>  
                      <td>techno</td>  
                      <td>2018-01-08</td> 
                      <td>20.00</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>


              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td>EYOE pres. Kite Base</td>  
                      <td>corsica studios</td>  
                      <td>techno</td>  
                      <td>2018-01-08</td> 
                      <td>11.00</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>


              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td>egg presents</td>  
                      <td>egg</td>  
                      <td>techno</td>  
                      <td>2018-01-08</td> 
                      <td>10.00</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>
```

Here is My PHP / SQL Request

```
$query = "  
       SELECT * FROM event  
       WHERE  event_date = '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  AND  genre = '".$_POST["request"]."' AND  price <= '".$_POST["request1"]."'
  ";      
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
    $output .= '  
     <table> 
      <thead>
             <tr>  
                 <th>Event</th>  
                 <th>Venue</th>  
                 <th>Genre</th>  
                 <th>Date</th> 
                 <th>Price</th>  
            </tr>  
             </thead>
            ';  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
  {  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
       {  
            $output .= ' 
              <tbody>
            <tr>  
                      <td >'. $row["event_name"] .'</td>  
                      <td >'. $row["venue_name"] .'</td>  
                      <td >'. $row["genre"] .'</td>  
                      <td >'. $row["event_date"] .'</td> 
                      <td >'. $row["price"] .'</td>  
                 </tr>  
                  </tbody>
                    </table> 
            ';  

       }  
  }
```

What am I doing wrong in the Ajax Request ?

Comment: I think you should move `<tbody>` before the loop, and `</tbody></table>` after the loop.

Comment: You are not using AJAX anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50286376/145346 (contains the JS)

Answer (score 1):

As You can see from comments try to put `<tbody>` and `</tbody>` out from `while` loop:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM event  
          WHERE  event_date = '".$_POST["to_date"]."' 
          AND genre = '".$_POST["request"]."' 
          AND price <= '".$_POST["request1"]."'";      
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
$output .= '<table> 
              <thead>
                <tr>  
                  <th>Event</th>  
                  <th>Venue</th>  
                  <th>Genre</th>  
                  <th>Date</th> 
                  <th>Price</th>  
               </tr>  
             </thead>
             <tbody>';  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
        $output .= '<tr>  
                     <td >'. $row["event_name"] .'</td>  
                     <td >'. $row["venue_name"] .'</td>  
                     <td >'. $row["genre"] .'</td>  
                     <td >'. $row["event_date"] .'</td> 
                     <td >'. $row["price"] .'</td>  
                    </tr>';  
   }
   $output.='</tbody>';  
}
else{
    //You can add some code if there are no result and then close </TDOBY>
    $output.='</tbody>';
}
//I suggest to add <tfoot> also before close <table>
$output .= '<tfoot>
              <tr>  
                <th>Event</th>  
                <th>Venue</th>  
                <th>Genre</th>  
                <th>Date</th> 
                <th>Price</th>  
             </tr>  
           </tfoot>
           </table>';
```